# How to configure a svn repository to auto set properties for every new objects commited?

Tags: svn

How could i set svn:needs-lock enabled for every new object added on a svn repository?

I'm aware that i can use auto properties but i have no idea how it works or how to set it up on an existing repository because the svn document isn't very clear for me.

Thanks in advance!

edit: i'm using svn 1.9

Answer (score 1):

Re-read [Repository Dictated Configuration — Part 2 of 3: Autoprops blog post from Collab](http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/the-road-to-repository-dictated-configuration-day-2) ("The svn:auto-props Property" section) - it's very clean (at least for me). In short:

- Create new repository, checkout root of repo (or checkout also repo-root for old)
- Add new property  (`svn propset svn:auto-props ...`):  smth. like `*.* = svn:needs-lock=yes`
- Commit this change
- Try to add some files to WC and propget|proplist these added files

Comment: Autoprops are also described in SVNBook: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.auto